# How to use gulp-browser-sync with PhpStorm for .php files

Tags: php, gulp, frontend, phpstorm, browser-sync

How to connect browser-sync an PhpStorm. There is no problem when I use **.html** files, but with **.php** files, I get an error:

`Cannot GET /`

When setting up browser-sync in gulpfile.js people specify a proxy (they use an open server). But I can't figure out where to set/ get it in PS. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t configure browser-sync without “Open Server” so I just downloaded it. In gulpfile.js in browser-sync setup I set **proxy:** instead of **server:**

```
function browserSync() {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: 'my project domain',
        notify: false,
    });
}
```

The solution is to use "build-in preview" in PhpStorm is inconvenient